# UDPClient doesn't Receive data

Tags: c#, sockets, udpclient

I have 2 Ifaces on my PC. I send a request through all Ifaces. But I receive data through 1 Iface. However, in Wireshark I see all data through all Ifaces. This works if I loop through all the interfaces instead IPAddress.Any.

```
public static List<byte[]> ReceiveArrayData(int port, byte response, int timeout)
    {
        byte[] data;
        List<byte[]> result = new List<byte[]>();

        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(port);
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            if (udpClient.Available > 0)
            {   // получаем данные
                data = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                if (data[0] == response)
                {
                    result.Add(data);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(Functions.ByteArrayToString(data));
                }
            }
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > timeout)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        udpClient.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: hmm! It works if I disabled windows firewall. I have to add rule. But I tryed add my udp port  in  an exception firewall, it doesn't  work

Comment: It works after I added my application access to public network in firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I added my application access to public network in windows firewall